# Extract array of array as a Hash table with key variable of the array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, hashtable

I have got array'arr',as I have search criteria **name=abc.def** and need split('.') the names go through all nodes as follow firstly search for **name=abc** then should go deeper in all matches, where I should continue with the second part of the search criteria - child **name='def'** (which is actually second part of the initial search keyword- "abc.def")
Here is the data which I should go through:

```
vars={1.1.1:{"no": "1.1.1","name": "Foo"}}

    let arr = [
            { 
              "no": "1",
              "name": "abc",
              "child" : [
                  { 
                      "no": "1.1",
                      "name": "def",
                      "child":[
                               "no": "1.1",
                               "name": "def",
                               "child":[...]
                                "var" : [
                                         {
                                          "no": "1.1.1.1",
                                          "name": "Foo"
                                          }
                                         ]

                      "var" : [
                          {
                              "no": "1.1.1",
                              "name": "Foo"
                          },
                          {
                              "no": "1.1.2",
                              "name": "jkl"
                          }
                          ] 
                  },
                  { 
                      "no": "1.2",
                      "name": "Foo",
                      "child" : [
                          {
                              "no": "1.2.1",
                              "name": "Foo"
                          },
                          {
                              "no": "1.2.2",
                              "name": "aaaaaaa"
                          }
                          ] 
                  }
              ]
              },
           { 
              "no": "2",
              "name": "abc2",
              "child" : [
                  { 
                      "no": "2.1",
                      "name": "Foo",
                      "child" : [
                          {
                              "no": "1.1.1",
                              "name": "ghi"
                          },
                          {
                              "no": "1.1.2",
                              "name": "jkl"
                          }
                          ] 
                  },
                  { 
                      "no": "2.2",
                      "name": "ghssssi",
                      "child" : [
                          {
                              "no": "2.2.1",
                              "name": "ghssssi"
                          },    
                          {
                              "no": "2.2.2",
                              "name": "asass"
                          }
                          ] 
                  }
              ]
          }
        ];
```

Expected result:
  to go through the hierarchy and extract info of all "var" deeper in child
in and after module with name="def", and to collect all matches in hash table 
Output :

```
vars={};
vars[1.1.1]={ "no": "1.1.1","name": "Foo"}
vars[1.1.2]={ "no": "1.1.2","name": "jkl"}
vars[1.1.1.1]={ "no": "1.1.1.1","name": "Foo"}
...
```

For instance:

Comment: Hi, it's hard to understand what you're asking. Could you edit your question so it looks like this: "I have this data .... I need this output ... My code so far .....  I need help with ......"

Comment: I understood what you are trying to do. Check out my answer and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Your array is invalid. And what is the purpose of `vars={1.1.1:{"no": "1.1.1","name": "Foo"}}` at the top of the snippet?

Answer (score 0):

We can use [String.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to split `path` values to access each property individually.

Then we can return the content of the final `child` array as an object.

```js
let arr = [ { "no": "1", "name": "abc", "child" : [ { "no": "1.1", "name": "def", "child" : [ { "no": "1.1.1", "name": "Foo" }, { "no": "1.1.2", "name": "jkl" } ] }, { "no": "1.2", "name": "Foo", "child" : [ { "no": "1.2.1", "name": "Foo" }, { "no": "1.2.2", "name": "aaaaaaa" } ] } ] }, { "no": "2", "name": "abc2", "child" : [ { "no": "2.1", "name": "Foo", "child" : [ { "no": "1.1.1", "name": "ghi" }, { "no": "1.1.2", "name": "jkl" } ] }, { "no": "2.2", "name": "ghssssi", "child" : [ { "no": "2.2.1", "name": "ghssssi" }, { "no": "2.2.2", "name": "asass" } ] } ] } ];

function findItem(arr, path, vars) {
  var properties = path.split('.').filter(item => item.trim() !== '');
  var value = arr;

  for (let property of properties) {
    if (Array.isArray(value)) {
      value = value.find(item => item.name === property);
    } else if (value && value['child']) {
      value = value.child.find(item => item.name === property);
    }
  }
  
  if (value && value['child']) {
    value.child.forEach(item => {
      vars[item.no] = item;
    });
  }

  return vars;
}

let vars = {};

vars = findItem(arr, "abc.def", vars);

console.log(vars);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in 2 steps:

- search for your target object recursively (based on the string path)
- extract `var` objects in the target object and all of its children (also recursively)

```js
const arr = [{
    "no": "1",
    "name": "abc",
    "child": [{
        "no": "1.1",
        "name": "def",
        "child": [{
          "no": "1.1",
          "name": "def",
          "child": [],
          "var": [{
            "no": "1.1.1.1",
            "name": "Foo"
          }]
        }],
        "var": [{
            "no": "1.1.1",
            "name": "Foo"
          },
          {
            "no": "1.1.2",
            "name": "jkl"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "no": "1.2",
        "name": "Foo",
        "child": [{
            "no": "1.2.1",
            "name": "Foo"
          },
          {
            "no": "1.2.2",
            "name": "aaaaaaa"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "no": "2",
    "name": "abc2",
    "child": [{
        "no": "2.1",
        "name": "Foo",
        "child": [{
            "no": "1.1.1",
            "name": "ghi"
          },
          {
            "no": "1.1.2",
            "name": "jkl"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "no": "2.2",
        "name": "ghssssi",
        "child": [{
            "no": "2.2.1",
            "name": "ghssssi"
          },
          {
            "no": "2.2.2",
            "name": "asass"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];

function find(path, data) {
  function _search([key, ...rest], arr) {
    const found = (arr || []).find(o => o.name === key);
    return rest.length && found ? _search(rest, found.child) : found;
  }
  return _search(path.split('.'), data)
}

function extractVars(obj, vars = {}) {
  (obj || {}).var.forEach(v => vars[v.no] = v);
  (obj || {}).child.forEach(c => extractVars(c, vars));
  return vars;
}

const target = find('abc.def', arr);
const vars = extractVars(target);
console.log('Target object:', target);
console.log('Vars:', vars);
```